# In Rails, a standard way to include GEM is config.gem 'name' or gem 'name'; what about standard way to include plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I think I understand it as, if it is Rails 2.x

```
config.gem 'gem_name'   # in config/environment.rb, and then rake gems:install
```

and in Rails 3.x

```
gem 'gem_name'          # in Gemfile, and then bundle install
```

these are the two standard ways to add a gem into a Rails project.

Is there a standard way to add a plugin?  It seems that it usually get installed as

```
script/plugin install _________________.git
```

and what is the standard way to include it?

(I think the current recommendation is to use gem or bundler, but what if we just need to use plugin in a particular situation?)

Answer (score 2):

After running `script/plugin install`, the plugin ends up in `vendor/plugins`, the contents of which are included automatically on startup. If that folder is checked into version control, you're good to go.

Comment: so Rails 2.x and 3.x both will automatically load anything inside of `vendor/plugins`... and it is not true for anything in `vendor/gems`...  anybody knows which part of Rails code does that?

Comment: @動靜能量: That's right :) Not sure where the plugin loader code is. Why do you ask?

Comment: @動靜能量: Got a bit closer. [railties/lib/rails/application.rb](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3022ce4f723075d201d9a20f7bca3537aa76a7d8/railties/lib/rails/application.rb#L85) loads the initializers from `Plugin.all` into the application initializers. [Plugin.all](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/plugin.rb#L29) loads those plugins straight from the `vendor/plugins` directory listing.

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 3.x you need to install plugins with `rails plugin install`

Alternative way is to clone git repo into `plugins` directory:

```
cd vendor/plugins/    
git clone http://github.com/__plug_name.git
```

or add as submodule to application:

```
git submodule add http://github.com/__plug_name.git vendor/plugins/__plug_name
```